# How to add custom nested tags in PyYaml?

Tags: python, pyyaml

I want to be able to use nested tags

I got the custom tags working separately using the below code, but unable to use both in same value

```
SafeLoader.add_constructor("!include", include)
SafeLoader.add_constructor("!path", gen_path)
```

This is how my sample yaml would look

```
key: !include !path special_file.yaml
```

**Note:**

!path => Generates a special path after some processing from mysql

!include => loads that yaml content of a file into the current reading data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours are shorthand tags and if you look at the production rule for that in the YAML 1.1 specification, you'll see:

```
[112]   c-ns-shorthand-tag  ::=   ( c-primary-tag-handle ns-tag-char+ )
                                | ( ns-secondary-tag-handle ns-uri-char+ )
                                | ( c-named-tag-handle ns-uri-char+ )
```

That rule is only used in the tag property:

```
[110]   c-ns-tag-property   ::=   c-verbatim-tag | c-ns-shorthand-tag
                                | c-ns-non-specific-tag
```

And that is used in the node property:

```
[107]   c-ns-properties(n,c)    ::=   ( c-ns-tag-property
                                      ( s-separate(n,c) c-ns-anchor-property )? )
                                    | ( c-ns-anchor-property
                                      ( s-separate(n,c) c-ns-tag-property )? )
```

As you can see, none of these include repetition of the tag element itself, only for characters within a tag ( `ns-tag-char+` ).

Therefore you cannot have multiple tags on a single node in YAML.

The YAML 1.1 spec that PyYAML partly implements, was replaced over ten years ago by YAML 1.2, but that has the same restriction, so it won't bring you anything to upgrade your YAML parser.

Comment: One thing you might consider trying is change the parser to relax the constraint that a plain scalar cannot start with an `!` when you have already encountered a tag on the node and then check during construction of the scalar if it started with an `!` and was unquoted. Since your scalar is simple (i.e. a string and not some collection) this is probably possible.